# How to iterate GLMs in H2O

Tags: r, regression, glm, h2o

My dataset looks like this:

```
rownum  a        b      y  x
1     |  A   |   a    |1 | a
2     |  B   |   a    |1 | a
3     |  C   |   a    |1 | a
4     |  D   |   a    |0 | b
5     |  E   |   a    |0 | a
6     |  F   |   a    |0 | b
```

I want to create many h2o.frames that are based on tissue identity. Like this:

a:

```
rownum  a        b     y    x
1     |  A   |   a    |1 | a
2     |  D   |   a    |0 | a
3     |  F   |   a    |0 | a
```

b:

```
rownum  a      b       y  x
1     |  B   |   a    |1 | b
2     |  C   |   a    |1 | b
3     |  E   |   a    |0 | b
```

While I am currently doing it manually, that becomes difficult when I add more tissues to the dataset.

I also want to then push those h2o.frames to h2o.glm and iteratively save the model.

```
"INSERT x NAME HERE" = h2o.glm(y = "y", x = 
c("a","b"), 
training_frame = ITERATE H2O FRAMES HERE, family = 'poisson')
```

and then save the model

```
INSERT x NAME HERE <- h2o.saveModel(object= INSERT x NAME 
HERE, force=TRUE)
```

I would appreciate any help or advice you might have. I do know about interaction terms in GLM, but would like to do this for now.

Comment: Can you explain what this means?  "While I am currently doing it manually, that becomes difficult when I add more tissues to the dataset."  What do you mean by "manually" and what is the specific difficulty you are having... running out of memory?  It would be helpful if you posted the code you are currently using to do this and to show why it's not working.

Comment: I can manually select the rows I want like this: Adipose_Tissue <- as.h2o(df[df$tissues == 'Adipose Tissue',c(1,2,4)])    But I don't want to repeat this command for let's say...200 tissues.  The difficulty I am having is not to do with memory, just that I can't figure out how to automate this.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I see what you're asking now -- you just need to know how to subset rows of a H2OFrame based on the value in the "tissue" column to create a new frame.

Comment: Yes.  And I want to pass those frames into the h2o.glm function and save the outputs seperately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide the data directly, I copied your example from above as an R data.frame.

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Example data as an R data.frame
df <- data.frame(genes = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"),
                 samples = c("a","a","a","a","a","a"),
                 y = c(1,1,1,0,0,0),
                 tissue = c("Muscle","Brain","Brain","Muscle","Brain","Muscle"))

# Convert R data.frame to H2OFrame
hf <- as.h2o(df)
```

However, I assume you have this data in a CSV on your computer, so in reality, what you'd do is this:

```
# Load data from disk directly into H2O cluster
hf <- h2o.importFile("tissue_samples.csv")
```

Now that you have the data in an H2OFrame, there are only a few more steps:

```
# List of unique tissue types
tissue_types <- as.list(h2o.unique(hf$tissue))

# Create list of frames (one for each tissue type)
frames <- sapply(tissue_types, function(t) hf[(hf[,"tissue"] == t),])

# Set up h2o.glm arguments
x <- c("genes", "samples")
y <- "y"

# List of glms (one for each tissue type)
glms <- sapply(frames, function(fr) h2o.glm(x = x, y = y, 
                       family = "poisson", training_frame = fr))

# Save the models
model_names <- sapply(glms, function(m) h2o.saveModel(m, path = "/Users/me/", force = TRUE))

# Look at model names
print(model_names)
# [1] "/Users/me/GLM_model_R_1497937770060_222"
# [2] "/Users/me/GLM_model_R_1497937770060_223"
```

Comment: Yep, you can use `%in%` or `h2o.match()`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/h2o/versions/3.10.4.6/topics/h2o.match

Comment: It's probably cleaner to use `==` instead of the `%in%` since that is more common in base R, so I updated the answer.

Comment: @ErinLeDell - is it possible to pass the tissue name into `model_id` ? I'm trying to find a way to make sense of all the model names.

Comment: @RyanJohn Yes, you would have to set the `model_id` parameter in the `h2o.glm()` function, which means in the code above you would have to reformulate the `sapply()` function and the anonymous function it applies to.  The `h2o.saveModel()` function will use the name of the model id (you can't change it here, it must be set at train time).